# solving least square

Tags: linear-algebra

I know and understand that $\ Ax = B $ is solved by $\ x= A^{-1}B $

and this can be written in python as

```
np.linalg.solve(A,B)
```

However I am unsure how to solve:

$\ \frac12 ||Gx -d||^2 + \frac a2 ||x||^2  $

I need to find a way to transform it into $\ Ax = B $

I thought of doing :

$\ \frac12  (Gx -d)(Gx -d)^t + \frac a2 xx^t  $

$\ \frac12 ( Gx -d)(G^tx^t - d^t) + \frac a2 xx^t  $

but not sure how to carry on

Please note that G is a matrix , x and d are vectors and a is a constant

Comment: With "solving" you mean minimize?

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure that $d$ is a vector, rather than a matrix.

Comment: yes , I want to minimize

Comment: yes you are right, d is a vector

Comment: You are doing ridge regression. See here for how to solve it in Python: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html.

Comment: I have to get to some Ax=b and then do linalg.solve() and that would be direction for newton method, I believe instead of directly applying this method. However, I am really bad in Linear Algebra and tried for hours to search how I can transform it into Ax=b but couldn't know

Comment: It might be nice to know that np.linalg.solve does not compute the inverse of A. It does an LU factorization of A then solves the system using forward and backward substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we have a minimum at $\mathbf x$, all the partial derivatives must be zero.

Let's start with $x_1$ and let's assume we minimize only $\|G\mathbf x -\mathbf d\|^2$. Then:
\begin{align}\frac\partial{\partial x_1}\Bigg[\|G\mathbf x -\mathbf d\|^2\Bigg]
&=\frac\partial{\partial x_1}\Bigg[(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d)^t(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d)  \Bigg] \\
&=\left(G\frac\partial{\partial x_1}\mathbf x\right)^t(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d)
+(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d)^t\left(G\frac\partial{\partial x_1}\mathbf x\right) \\
&= (G\mathbf e_1)^t(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d)
+(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d)^t(G\mathbf e_1) = 0
\end{align}
Note that $(G\mathbf e_1)^t(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d)$ is a scalar. Therefore it is equal to its transpose $((G\mathbf e_1)^t(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d))^t = (G\mathbf x -\mathbf d)^t(G\mathbf e_1)$.

So:
$$\frac\partial{\partial x_1}\Bigg[\|G\mathbf x -\mathbf d\|^2\Bigg]
= 2(G\mathbf e_1)^t(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d) = 0
$$
Furthermore, $G\mathbf e_1$ is the first column vector in $G$, and $(G\mathbf e_1)^t$ is that same column vector written as a row. As the equation must not only be true for $\mathbf e_1$, but for every standard unit vector, we can write it as the set of equations:
$$2(G)^t(G\mathbf x -\mathbf d) = \mathbf 0$$

When we apply the same method to your original expression $\frac12 \|G\mathbf x - \mathbf d\|^2 + \frac a2 \|\mathbf x\|^2$, we get:
$$G^t(G\mathbf x - \mathbf d) + a \mathbf x = \mathbf 0$$
Rewrite to get:
$$(G^t G + aI)\mathbf x = G^t\mathbf d$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

To find the minimum, you need to consider

$$\frac{d}{dx} (\frac12 ||Gx -d||^2 + \frac a2 ||x||^2) = 0.$$

This should give you a linear system $Ax = B$

Comment: so this is actually a function?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you can not put it in a form of $$\Vert Ax - b \Vert^2$$ unless your $a = 0$, then $A = G$ and $b = d$.  To find the minimum and as @Pebeto mentions, you need to compute the derivative wrt $x$.

Comment: is that actually a function on which I can calculate the gradient and the hessian? then do the solve?

Comment: If you;re referring to $\frac12 ||Gx -d||^2 + \frac a2 ||x||^2$, of course it is a function in which you can compute its gradient and Hessian.